# SharePoint 2010 to 2013 upgrade - DB patch level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, upgrade

Trying to confirm whether SharePoint 2010 database on RTM with CU 14.0.5123.5000 can be upgraded to SharePoint 2013. If possible, does it have any drawbacks compared to SP 2010 being on SP1 or upper level.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the minimum requirements, there is no specification for db schema versions so it is at least worth a try.  In general though, you should stay current with service packs.

Comment: I second you regarding maintaining on current Service Pack level and is part of a plan to apply at least up to SP1. We are planning to upgrade to SP 2013 and it struck to me what if patching could be bypassed altogether to save outage and time. Last couple of days I have been looking around to confirm this but no luck so far though.

Comment: Keep in mind there is no direct upgrade to 2013.  In fact, I had a VM that I even uninstalled SP 2010 from completely and it still detected some artifacts.  You will need to do a clean install, which means you can operate off of a copy of the databases.  This will allow the existing system to run while you are testing the upgrade of the dbs.